# Accessing scripts once the script has been written

Tags: google-apps-script

I followed the tutorial here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/gmail_filter_sms#section3

I'd like to go back and edit the time-frame of the trigger but I can't find the script. It's been working for several days now and continues to work but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Can someone lend a hand and tell me where I can go to edit the script I had originally saved?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you created a standalone script or is this in a Spreadsheet/Document/Sites container?

Answer (score 1):

According to the tutorial you were following, you created a container-bound script. You can read about scripts and containers [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scripts_containers) to get to know the differences.

The tutorial creates a script in the context of a spreadsheet ([see steps 5-6 here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/gmail_filter_sms#section1)), and you should be able to find the script pretty easily once you track down what spreadsheet you made it in. I'm fairly certain that it can still be executed if the spreadsheet is in your trash, but I don't have any documentation to back that up.